# TextField appears on stage when it's not a child of DisplayContainer?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, children, stage, addchild

Really need some help understanding whats going on after

```
textFields[i].text = thisWord.charAt(i);
```

I understand it updates a value at that particular index, I just can't figure out why it affects:

```
textContainer.addChild(tempText);
textFields.push(tempText);
```

The value that gets changed appears on the stage but I don't understand why because it's never added as a child of textContainer.

```
var loader:URLLoader;
var allWords:Array;
var thisWord:String;

var textContainer:MovieClip;

var textFields:Array;
var textStyle:TextFormat;
var underline:MovieClip;

function init():void
{
    loader = new URLLoader();
    allWords = new Array();

    textContainer = new MovieClip();
    textFields = new Array();

    textStyle = new TextFormat();
    textStyle.font = "Courier New";
    textStyle.size = 48;
    textStyle.bold = true;

    textContainer.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - 50;
    addChild(textContainer);

    loader.load(new URLRequest("words.txt"));
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, textLoaded);
    guess_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, guess);

}

function textLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    var tempText:TextField;

    var stringOfWords:String = event.target.data;
    allWords = stringOfWords.split(",");
    thisWord = allWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * allWords.length)];
    trace(thisWord);

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < thisWord.length; i++)
    {
        tempText = new TextField();
        tempText.defaultTextFormat = textStyle;
        tempText.name = "textField" + i;
        tempText.text = "1";//for restart

        tempText.width = 48;
        tempText.x = i * tempText.width;
        tempText.selectable = false;
        textContainer.addChild(tempText);

        textFields.push(tempText);

        if (thisWord.charAt(i) != " ")
        {
            underline = new Underline();
            underline.x = tempText.x + tempText.width / 3;
            underline.y = tempText.y + tempText.height / 2 + 5;
            //textContainer.addChild(underline);
        }
    }

    textContainer.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - textContainer.width / 2;



}

function guess(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (guess_txt.text != "")
    {
        if (thisWord.indexOf(guess_txt.text) != -1)
        {
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < textFields.length; i++)
            {
                if (thisWord.charAt(i) == guess_txt.text)
                {
                    textFields[i].text = thisWord.charAt(i);
                    trace(textFields[i].text);
                }
            }

        }
        else if (guesses_txt.text == "")
        {
            guesses_txt.appendText(guess_txt.text);
        }
        else
        {
            guesses_txt.appendText("," + guess_txt.text);
        }
    }

    guess_txt.text = "";
    findch();
}

init();
```

I'm pretty sure theres a rule I'm missing or not understanding....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pointed out right in your question that it actually *is* being added. Each `tempText` object you create in that loop is added to `textContainer` which had been added to stage in the constructor.

```
textContainer.addChild(tempText);
```

`textFields[i].text = thisWord.charAt(i);` is just updating the text of the TextField at the specific index within the array. There is no reason the text on the stage *should not* be updating here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'm afraid Im still not getting it though :/. If whats showing up on stage are "tempText" objects added in the textContainer... why does changing the index of "textFields" change the values of tempText?

Comment: There is no code that "reassigns" textFields[i].text = thisWord.charAt(i); to "tempText"

Comment: I'm having a huge "OH" moment. I was thinking that textFields.push(tempText); was pushing the "values" not the actual object into the array, and that textFields[i].text = thisWord.charAt(i); changed the value, but didn't add it to the stage. When really it was changing the object that was already on stage.

I think I just needed someone to repeat it to me another way. Thought I was going crazy. Thanks.